# In gitlab-ci.yml pipeline how can I use only and except keywords properly?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

This is how my project's structure looks like

```
├── main_project
│   ├── service1
│   │   ├── [...]
│   ├── service2
│   │   ├── [...]
│   ├── docs
│   │   ├── [...]
│   ├── .gitlab-ci.yml
    └── Makefile
```

My .gitlab.ci-yml

```
 [...]
 service1_build:
  image: image
  stage: build
  script:
    - #doing something
  only:
    changes:
      - /service1/**/*
      - /.gitlab-ci.yml
      - /Makefile
  except:
    changes:
      - /docs/**/*

 service2_build:
  image: image
  stage: build
  script:
    - #doing something
  only:
    changes:
      - /service2/**/*
      - /.gitlab-ci.yml
      - /Makefile
  except:
    changes:
      - /docs/**/*

 test:
  image: image
  stage: test
  needs:
    - service1_build
    - service2_build
  script:
    - #doing something
  except:
    changes:
      - /docs/**/*

 service1_docker:
  image: image
  stage: docker
  needs:
    - test
  script:
    - #doing something
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    changes:
      - /service1/**/*
      - /.gitlab-ci.yml
      - /Makefile
  except:
    changes:
      - /docs/**/*

 service2_docker:
  image: image
  stage: docker
  needs:
    - test
  script:
    - #doing something
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    changes:
      - /service2/**/*
      - /.gitlab-ci.yml
      - /Makefile
  except:
    changes:
      - /docs/**/*
 [...]
```

I tried this, but it is not working properly. For example, if I change a file in `docs` folder, the `test` job will be executed by the pipeline.

These are the rules that I want to be applied to each job:

- **service1_build**: run on all branches, when there is any modification within the `service1` folder or if `Makefile` or `.gitlab-ci.yml` has been changed. But it should not run when files in `docs` folder have been modified.
- **service2_build**: run on all branches, when there is any modification within the `service2` folder or if `Makefile` or `.gitlab-ci.yml` has been changed. But it should not run when files in `docs` folder have been modified.
- **test**: run on all branches every time, except when files in `docs` folder have been modified.
- **service1_docker**: run only on `master`, when there is any modification within the `service1` folder or if `Makefile` or `.gitlab-ci.yml` has been changed. But it should not run when files in `docs` folder have been modified.
- **service2_docker**: run only on `master`, when there is any modification within the `service2` folder or if `Makefile` or `.gitlab-ci.yml` has been changed. But it should not run when files in `docs` folder have been modified.

Is this applicable like this? Or how should I handle this? When I am giving the path, it always looking it from the `gitlab-ci.yml's` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your project structure, you should try to change your only/except paths like this :

```
only:
    changes:
      - main_project/service1/**/*
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      - Makefile
  except:
    changes:
      - main_project/docs/**/*
```

This include the `main_project` directory.

You should also add some optional needs to your test job, because if there is only updates on service1, the test job will look to the service2 job and fail :

```
test:
  stage: test
  needs:
    - job: service1_build
      optional: true
    - job: service2_build
      optional: true
```

I made some tests with these new fix and your rules are working properly : https://gitlab.com/sandbox_fm/ci-rules.

You also should consider [moving from only/except to rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) because :

> only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the
> preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.

Comment: Sorry, my directory tree wasn't good in the question. I modified it here so I guess the path should be good. But the test job will be executed when I modify a file in the docs folder. I will try to use your code as an example and let's see if it is working for me or not.

Comment: Check my example because my tests show that test job was not executed with this.